# How to see an output of a file that has been created by Formatter Class

Tags: java, file, formatter

I write the below code & it makes a file & writes to it perfectly, but I want to see the contents of the file in output, but I only get this message: "java.io.BufferedWriter@140e19d".
I don't get that! Can anyone please explain to me Why I get this message? and What should I do to see the contents of the file?
tnx.

Here is My code:

```
package com.example.idea;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Formatter file = null;
    Scanner sc =null;
    try {
        file = new Formatter("D:\\test.txt");
        file.format("%s %s", "Hello", "World");
        sc = new Scanner(String.valueOf(file));
        while (sc.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(sc.next());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (file != null) {
            file.close();
        }
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }




    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you expected that `String.valueOf(file)` would return the contents you wrote to `file`, but that's not what happens.  Instead, close `file`, re-open your file with a `FileInputStream` and wrap that stream in a `Scanner`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson tnx for your comment, but I try it and I think that's not working with Formatter, because my file created with Formatter!
Can you please write the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum change you need to get your code working is to replace the line

```
sc = new Scanner(String.valueOf(file));    // WRONG!!!
```

with

```
file.close();
sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("D:\\test.txt"));
```

No doubt you were expecting `String.valueOf(file)` to somehow give you access to the *contents* of the file `D:\test.txt`, in such a way that a `Scanner` could then read those contents.  **A `Formatter` only *writes* data**; it can't read the data back.  For that, you need a `FileInputStream`.

So, first, finish up writing to the file by closing the `Formatter`:

```
file.close();
```

Now `D:\test.txt` is just a file on disk like any other, and is now available to  be opened for reading with a `FileInputStream`:

```
new FileInputStream("D:\\test.txt")
```

If you like, you can wrap that stream in a `Scanner`:

```
sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("D:\\test.txt"));
```

and then process the data with calls to `Scanner` methods.

Here's a more radically reworked version of your example that more clearly highlights the the separation between the writing and reading operations:

```
public class Main
{
    private static void writeFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Formatter file = null;
        try {
            file = new Formatter(fileName);
            file.format("%s %s", "Hello", "World");
        } finally {
            if (file != null) {
                file.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(sc.next());
            }
        } finally {
            if (sc != null) {
                sc.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String fileName = "test.txt";
        try {
            writeFile(fileName);
            readFile(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
sc = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer my help to solve the issue.

Comment: @mentallurg that's not gonna work because you get this error: " Cannot resolve constructor 'Scanner(java.util.Formatter)' "